# cache busting without version or hash

Tags: javascript, cache-control

We have 2 applications (on the same domain).
Application 1 is the consumer and always uses the latest Javascript file from Application 2.

In application 1:

How can we update the file.js in application 2 without asking application 1 to change and deploy the code? A user of application 1 should not have to do CTRL+F5 or clear cache.

What would be the best technique while keeping cache busting working?

Comment: Cache settings are pretty much set at the http header level, and are the domain of the web server.  It would help if you provided more details about your server setup and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Windows server with IIS. In IIS we have multiple applications under same domain maintainted by multiple teams. Some application (producers) within that domain provide JS components which are used by the other applications (consumers). The producers must be able to deploy new versions without asking to the consumers to adapt the code and having to deploy.

Comment: You could use timestamps in application 1 for cache busting, but you really don't want that. Just provide reasonable http caching from application 2 - with etags.